# Division by a series with no coefficients

Tags: numerics, series-expansion

I know it is strange, but it seems MA is unable to compute a simple series expansion

```
a[1]=-1.0714379525829776`+0.020674495099438535` I;
a[2]=1.0714377324307713` -0.020674497100401874` I;
b[1]=-1.0916908367607507`+0.05485853112917313` I;
b[2]=1.0970191920263659` -0.04438231597079857` I;
b[3]=0.9999997798477938` -0.01000000200096334` I;
f= (a[1]+y)(a[2]+y)/(b[1]-b[2] y+b[3] y^2+y^3);
Series[f,{y,0.,5}]

Out[1]= 1/O[y+0.]^31539
```

`SeriesCoefficient` doe not work either, but `Apart` does. Why? What's going on here? So mysterious that I do not even know how to tag the question...

---

@MarcoB suggested to `Rationalize`. The result is

```
(1.05056 +0.0122096 I)
-(1.05504 +0.0225762 I) (y+0.)
+(1.10568 +0.0369162 I) (y+0.)^2
-(1.11448 +0.0479809 I) (y+0.)^3
+(1.16535 +0.0644737 I) (y+0.)^4
-(1.17832 +0.0765497 I) (y+0.)^5+O[y+0.]^6
```

I came up with

```
Series[#,{y,0,5}]&/@Apart[f]
```

yielding pretty much the same (but notice `y` instead of `y+0.` as the expansion parameter)

```
(1.05056 +0.0122096 I)
-(1.05504 +0.0225762 I) y
+(1.10568 +0.0369162 I) y^2
-(1.11448 +0.0479809 I) y^3
+(1.16535 +0.0644737 I) y^4
-(1.17832 +0.0765497 I) y^5+O[y]^6
```

So, if it is not a bug in `Series` why does `Series/@Apart` works?

Comment: What does `f + O[y]^5` return?

Comment: The problem seems numerical. Note that `ser = Series[Rationalize[f, 0], {y, 0, 5}]` works fine. You could then use `N[ser, <yourDesiredPrecision>]` for a numerical approximation.

Comment: @J.M. It returns almost the same. But maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, that the way out. But should it be tagged as a `bug`?

Comment: @yarchik I don't think so. See for instance: `Series[SetPrecision[f, 2], {y, 0., 5}]`. You can see where some members have an effective value of zero at that precision. This is caught when the evaluation is carried out at arbitrary precision, but at machine precision things simply don't go too well. That's a numerical precision problem, I'd argue, not a bug.

Comment: @MarcoB Hmm, not fully understand your argument. Why then `Apart` works? Thanks for the solution, its a way to go in hard cases like this one.

Comment: @yarchik If you clear the values of `a`, calculate the Series on symbolic f, then define `a` or substitute them into the series expression, it works. Alternatively, the calculation with $a$ values set to *any level* of arbitrary precision works as well (e.g. ``a[1] = SetPrecision[-1.0714379525829776` + 0.020674495099438535` I, 
   5];``). I mean, machine-precision `Series[Erf[y], {y, 30., 5}]` returns an error (albeit a more informative one), but arbitrary-precision ``Series[Erf[y], {y, 30.`6, 5}]`` does not. Is the former a bug? I would think not.

Comment: @yarchik "Why then Apart works?" - I don't know exactly, but perhaps because the calculation internally takes a path that does not lead to catastrophic loss of precision? Notice that, interestingly, `Series[Apart@f, {y, 0., 5}]` also works.

Comment: I am not seeing the claimed behavior so it is difficult to comment. What happen if you expand at exact 0 instead of .0?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Probably it only appears in certain versions. I have 11. The result is the same if I use exact 0.

Comment: Maybe it was a bug that got fixed? I'm told such things happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems numerical. Note that the following works fine:

```
ser = Series[Rationalize[f, 0], {y, 0, 5}]
```

You could then use `N[ser, <yourDesiredPrecision>]` for a numerical approximation: